# Python: OpenCV can not be loaded on windows xp

Tags: python, opencv, windows-xp, py2exe

I have a Python app built with Python, OpenCv and py2exe.

When I distribute this app and try to run it on a windows XP machine, I have an error on startup due to error loading cv2.pyd (opencv python wrapper)

I looked at cv2.pyd with dependency walker and noticed that some dlls are missing : ieshims.dll and wer.dll. Unfortunately copying these libs doesn't solve the issues some other dlls are missing or not up-to-date.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from 4 dlls which are copyied by py2exe: `msvfw32.dll` `msacm32.dll`, `avicap32.dll` and `avifil32.dll`

As I am building on Vista, I think that it forces the use of Vista dlls on Windows XP causing some mismatch when trying to load it.

I removed these 4 dlls and everything seems to work ok (in this case it use the regular system dlls.)